# VB Script Regional Settings

Tags: vbscript, regional-settings

Is it possible to set regional settings for a process through VB script?

```
Dim oEnv: Set oEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
oEnv.Item("NLS_LANG") = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252"
```

This is one bit of code I got. Not sure how it works though? I would like to set the standards and formats for my application specifically to United States from United Kingdom.

Thanks
 Nishant

Answer (score 0):

Your computer uses environment variables to remember certain internal settings for applications. You can view them by pressing Windows key (flag) + Pause/Break, selecting the Advanced tab, pressing the Environments Variables button and look into the System Variables section.

With the WshShell.Environment object, you can read and write these variables:

```
Option Explicit
dim wshshell, EnvVar
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim oEnv: Set oEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS") 

' This shows you all environment variables in your system:    
For each EnvVar in oEnv
    msgbox EnvVar
Next

' This shows you a particular environment variable:
msgbox oEnv.item("OS")

' And this sets a particular environment variable:
oEnv.Item("NLS_LANG") = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252"
```

`NLS_LANG` is a setting used by Oracle and sets the cultural settings. By setting it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` you tell your Oracle implementation what kind of culture you want to use on your specific system (remember, environment variables are per PC). You can find more information about that [on](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12129/nls_lang-when-using-multiple-oracle-homes) [the](https://repettas.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/importexport-nls-considerations-for-a-unicode-database/) [net](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-is-nlslang-environmental-variable.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. What I am trying to achieve is setting the Regional Settings specifically for my application. So this will be at the process level. I just came across SetLocale(). Will the be of help?

Comment: SetLocale() is used for setting the webpage locale through VBScript. Unless you are using ASP, I don't think it will work. I your application is interfacing with an Oracle database (especially installed on Unix) then you want to use the NLS_LANG system variable. Note: I am only shooting in the dark here. I am pretty familiar with VBScript etc., but not with Oracle settings and namespacing.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be set in the registry.  The registry path you use differs depending upon the version you are using.

**For Oracle version 7:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ORACLE"
strValueName = "NLS_LANG"
strValue = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252"

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
```

**For Oracle Database versions 8, 8i and 9i:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOMEx\
where "x" is the unique number identifying the Oracle home.
HOME0 is the first installation

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOMEx"
strValueName = "NLS_LANG"
strValue = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252"

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
```

**For Oracle Database 10g:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_<oracle_home_name>"
strValueName = "NLS_LANG"
strValue = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252"

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
```